# IndexOutOfRangeException: field_name in SQL Server select statement

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I don't know what the error is about. When I run my SQL statement in SQL Server or on vb.net query builder, I get no error and I get results. But when I run it from my vb.net code, I get this error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException:Invoice
>   at System.Data.ProvideBase.FieldNameLookup.GetORdrinal(String fieldName)
>   at Suste.mData.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdnal(String name).... (more texts)

This is my code:

```
Private Sub FillPulloutList(employee_id As Integer, transaction_date As Date)
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        query = "SELECT invoice As 'Invoice', product_id As 'Product ID', quantity As 'Quantity', amount As 'Amount', transaction_date As 'Date', employee_id As 'Employee ID' FROM pullouts_tbl " & _
                "WHERE (transaction_date = @transaction_date) AND (employee_id = @employee_id)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_transaction_date", transaction_date)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_employee_id", employee_id)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read
            PulloutListDGV.Rows.Add(dr("Invoice"), dr("Amount"))
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        cnn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have used this code over a hundred times in this program that I'm creating but didn't get any errors except for this one. Can you point to me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

This is my table if it helps

```
if not exists (select * from sys.tables where name = N'pullouts_tbl' and type = N'U')
begin
    create table pullouts_tbl
    (
        tid int identity(1,1) not null,
        transaction_date date not null,
        invoice int not null,
        product_id nchar(20) not null,
        quantity int not null,
        amount decimal(18,2) not null,
        employee_id nchar(20) not null

        constraint pullouts_tbl_tid_pk primary key clustered (tid)
        constraint pullouts_tbl_invoice_fk 
            foreign key (invoice) references invoice_tbl(invoice),
        constraint pullouts_tbl_product_id_fk 
            foreign key (product_id) references products_tbl(product_id),
        constraint pullouts_tbl_employee_id_fk 
            foreign key (employee_id) references employees_tbl(employee_id)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the issue is here:

```
PulloutListDGV.Rows.Add(dr("Invoice"), dr("Amount"))
```

One or both of those columns can not be found in the result set.  I notice that those two columns are both specified in the SQL code you assign to the `query` variable but you never assign that SQL to the `CommandText` of your `SqlCommand`.  You are presumably executing some other query.  This is an example of why you should create your command object where you use it.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I forgot the cmd = new SQLCommand (query,cnn)

Comment: You really should be using a local variable for that so it should not have been possible to make that mistake.  I'd suggest a local variable for the connection too, unless you really need to be able to use the same connection object in multiple methods.

Comment: I'd love to do that but I don't know how to implement it. Can you show me an example?

Comment: You just get rid of your current member variable and then, wherever that creates an error with an undeclared variable, you simply declare it as a local.