# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'counter' - beginner

Tags: c#, sql, exception

I've got a database that has two columns both are of type int.

One column is called "id" and the other "counter".

Im using an SQLDataReader to read from the database

```
int id = (int)reader3["id"];                                          
int counter = (int)reader3["counter"];
```

The first variable "id" returns the id value of the column fine.  But the second variable stops the execution with a System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'counter' error.

I cant really debug this error as counter does not exist in the current context.

---

```
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT id FROM categoryData WHERE CONVERT(DATE,Date) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),103) AND category = '" +
                            categoryList[i] + "'", con);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlDataReader reader3 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
while (reader3.Read())
{
  int id = (int)reader3["id"];      
  int counter = (int)reader3["counter"]; 

  cmd2.Parameters.Clear();
  con.Open();
  cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE categoryData SET counter = counter+1 WHERE 
    id = " + id + "", con);
  cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

  dateLabel.Text = categoryBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
  recordedLabel.Text = "Count is: " + counter;
  break;
}
```

Comment: show the sql query used

Comment: i like the fact you didnt splatter your whole project in a post. however this is lacking a bit to much code. please add the entire method which includes the sql

Comment: Ok, you are doing it wrong, dont do that

Comment: If code = wrong then Dont() end if?

Comment: Still missing info, what is `reader3`, where is the query for that? You are also open to sql injection attack.

Comment: Sorry I dont follow.  I may be doing it wrong indeed, im still learning. pretty much a beginner here.

Comment: `reader3.Read()` is reading the results of a query that is defined in code you aren't showing us.  You need to go further up your code block and show that query.

Comment: ha im being a dufus.  You have answered my question.

Comment: Sorry, was just making a joke. I wouldn't put the reader in a while loop with the update. You can most likely do this in one SQL statement, with better performance. As others suggested, add the code the populate reader3 and we can help.

Comment: ive not included the counter column in my query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IndexOutOfRangeException: field\_name in SQL Server select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261520/indexoutofrangeexception-field-name-in-sql-server-select-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error actually means the  your `select` statement does not contain a column named `counter` in it from whatever table you are selecting the  data.

So what you need to do is carefully check your query that it is returning a column named `counter` of type `int`.

The query associated with `reader3`  should be something like:

```
select id, counter from categoryData
where .......
```

**UPDATE:**

So from your updated questions it  is quite clear now that you are not selecting `counter` column in your query which probably you missed when adding query, so it should be :

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT id,counter FROM categoryData WHERE 
CONVERT(DATE,Date) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),103) AND category = '" +
                        categoryList[i] + "'", con);
```

### Important Caution!

and one more thing that is important here is  that do not do string concatenation in your queries, instead use [Parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) to be safe from [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Following would be the code to with Parameterized query :

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT id,couter FROM categoryData WHERE CONVERT(DATE,Date) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),103) AND category = @category",con);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", categoryList[i]);   
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Hope it  helps!

Comment: Please start using the parameters! It makes your code much more readable and safe.

Comment: I will.  Thanks for the advice, very helpful indeed.  Cant believe I made such a silly error.

Comment: Has anyone got a good tutorial source for using parameters?  Everyone I find is obtuse or overly long going on and on with Sql injection demos.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id, **counter** FROM categoryData WHERE...

EDIT: string concatenation in SqlQuery is not the best idea, this can be use to SqlInjection...

Comment: what a dufus I am

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your query.

`"SELECT id FROM categoryData ..."` "counter" isn't one of your fields you're retrieving.   It needs to say:

`"SELECT id, counter FROM categoryData ..."`